# Jiffy parse strange error when settgin locale to de

Tags: flutter, dart, locale

When trying to parse this string `03-02-2024 18:03:47` with Jiffy, I get an error only when the locale is set to `de` or `pl`. It works with other locales like `en`, `es`, `fr`, etc.

`Could not parse input '0302-2024 18:03:47', failed with the following error: FormatException: Trying to read - from 0302-2024 18:03:47 at 10`.

It says it cannot read the dash `-` from the date string, which is strange.

Tested with `03/02/2024 18:03:47` and the error changes to: `Trying to read / from`.

Tested also with `03 02 2024 18:03:47`. When blank, it works.

Here is my Jiffy function:
`Jiffy.parse("03-02-2024 18:03:47", pattern: "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss").fromNow()`

I am setting the locale in the build method:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    myLocale = Localizations.localeOf(context);
    setLocale(myLocale.languageCode);
}
```

And here is the `myLocale` function:

```
class _PageState extends State<Page> {
   void setLocale(locale) async {
      await Jiffy.setLocale(locale);
   }
}
```

Any ideas of what is going wrong with de locale `de` or `pl`?

**UPDATE:**

With locales `ar` (Arabic) and `fa` (Persian), the error changes to `Trying to read dd from` and the error remains the same even if I change the `-` to blank space:

`Could not parse input '03-02-2024 18:03:47', failed with the following error: FormatException: Trying to read dd from 03-02-2024 18:03:47 at 0`

Comment: Can you try alternative `languageCode`? `de_de` , `de_at` and `de_ch`

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! No change unfortunately.